# Python Loop Changing a Few Letters/Numbers in it

Tags: python

How can I make this code more efficient? I'm changing a few of the numbers each time but it's getting tedious because I have so many more to go. I've tried:

```
i=1
print('Enter Number of #',i,'Tickets Left: ')
TL+i=input()
P+i+Y = int(T+i)-int(TL+i)
```

But am getting a syntax error.

```
P1 = 1
P2 = 50
P3 = 1
P4 =1
P5 = 2
P6=2
P7=2
P8=2
P9=2
P10=2
P11=2
P12=2
P13= 3
P14=3
P15=3
P16=5
P17=5


T1=250
T2=250
T3 = 250
T4 = 250
T5 = 250
T6 = 250    
T7 = 250
T8 = 250
T9 = 250
T10 = 250

for i in range(1,10):
    print('Enter Number of #1 Tickets Left: ')
    TL1 = input()
    P1y = int(T1) - int(TL1)
    
    print('Enter Number of #2 Tickets Left: ')
    TL2 = input()
    P2y = int(T2) - int(TL2)
```

etc.

Comment: If you're ever numbering variables, you probably want to use a list: `p = [1, 50, 1, ...]` and then just access them with their index (starting at `0` eg., `p[0]`)

Comment: Syntax error due to `TL+i=input()`. What are you trying to achieve with this line?

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you go through some Python tutorial, you would certainly find a lot of inspiration for better solutions. A list of some recommended ones: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: @VladimirFokow I suspect they're trying to build a variable name. Of course Python doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify a variable name dynamically the same way you can modify a string -- luckily you don't need to!  Instead of having 10 different variables, create a single list with 10 values:

```
t_tickets = [250] * 10
p_tickets = [
    t - int(input(f"Enter Number of #{i} Tickets Left: "))
    for i, t in enumerate(t_tickets, 1)
]
```

`t_tickets` holds the ten `250` values (note that you don't really need a list for this purpose, but I assume that at some point these values might be different).  We then iterate over that list to generate ten values for `p_tickets` by subtracting the user input from the corresponding `t_tickets` value.